# php soap xml prefix error

Tags: php, soap

i'm using php soap, i have request xml bellow:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Search xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ExtraParamList i:nil="true" />
  <Form>
    <ProductId>20</Id>
  </Form>
</Search>
```

i have error : `The prefix 'i' is not defined.`

if delete `i:nil="true"` i have error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`